# How to redirect page on payment gateway to submit payment when admin place an order from back end

Tags: magento

When customer create an order on site then page will redirect to selected payment gateway page (world pay payment) to submit payment but i want to same thing in back end when admin create an order then page should redirect to selected payment gateway to submit payment.

How it will be possible.

Please Suggest

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to the quote.xml or sales.xml or custom.xml, (It depends on which plugin you are using)

In, you need to change the path to the url (path) you want to display